# Complex Sine bounded when $|\text{Im } z| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that $\sin z$ is bounded on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |\text{Im } z| < 1\}$.

I know how to prove that it is unbounded, but I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin z= \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is by noting that $\sin(z)$ is $2\pi$ periodic. So by continuity it is bounded on the compact set $[-\pi,\pi]+i[-1,1]$ and by periodicity this extends to boundedness on $\mathbb{R}+i[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of $\sin$?

With $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}(\exp{iz}-\exp(-iz))$ this is an easy exercise with substituting $z = x+iy$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\,z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|y|<1\,$

$$\sin z=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}e^{-y}-e^{-ix}e^y\right)\implies|\sin z|=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right)\le \ldots$$

Comment: How do you get from $|e^{ix}e^{-y} - e^{-ix}e^y|$ to  $e^{-y} + e^y$? I understand that $|e^{ix}|=1$, but for some reason, I'm not seeing this.

Comment: I didn't do that: I first applied the triangle inequality **and then** did what you suggest .

Comment: So $|e^{ix}e^{−y}−e^{−ix}e^{y}| \leq |e^{ix}e^{−y}|+|−e^{y}e^{−ix}| = |e^{−y}|+|−e^{y}| = e^{−y}+ e^{y} < 2e$ so $|\sin z| < e$.

Comment: For example, yes...